# Is there any possibility of showing home screen as background while the app loads my transparent launch image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to show the home screen or springboard in the background of launch image.

But what I actually get is in iOS 7

[image: iOS 7]

and in iOS 6.1

[image: iOS 6]

Is there any possibility of showing home screen or springboard in background while launching the app?

Comment: you can show any image as launch image just put one with some different background other than transparent as only one image can be set as launch image :)

Comment: Actually I want to display the homescreen in the background, thats why my launch image is transparent. @claric

Comment: Then just add it with your splash screen as it's background :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it. And any home screen screenshot you bundle with your app is never going to match a users actual home screen. As you've seen iOS covers the home screen when an app is launched even if you don't provide a launch image, and if you provide an incorrectly shaped one your app will be rejected at submission.

Just make a launch image as recommended by apple, with a minimal version of your interface on it. It's not a "splash screen" or an opportunity to shove your logo in the users face.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is take a screen shot of your home screen and then use that image as the start up image, you can't do anything dynamic to that image because that image is what the OS shows whilst loading you app, i.e. before your app has a chance to start running.

Comment: See this is what i want to tell you :)

Comment: For clearest results, you can also have multiple versions of the launch image for different screen sizes and resolutions.

Comment: So I cant do anything dynamic to my launch image. But thats what i want? I want my launch image to show current home screen as background.

Comment: Do I have to change any property to make my app display the home screen as background? Is there any other option other than this?

Comment: This is not going to work. How is a screen shot of the developers home screen going to look anything like a user's?

Comment: What you want to do is simply not possible.

Comment: Sorry I mis understood, I thought you mean home screen of your app, a lot of apps I work on have a first home screen that you navigate from and to.